# How to make predictions with Linear Regression Model?

Tags: java, apache-spark, linear-regression, apache-spark-ml

I am currently working on a linear regression project where I need to gather data, fit it on a model, and then make a prediction based on test data.

If I'm correct, simple linear regression works with two variables, X (independent) and Y (dependent). I have the following Dataset, where I consider the `time` column to be X and the `value` column to be Y:

```
+-----+------+
|value|minute|
+-----+------+
| 5000|   672|
| 6000|   673|
| 7000|   676|
| 8000|   678|
| 9000|   680|
+-----+------+
```

What I don't know is how to fit this Dataset correctly into a Linear Regression Model. I've worked with k-means before and what I did with it was create a `features` column in vector form. I did the same with this dataset:

```
VectorAssembler assembler = new VectorAssembler()
                .setInputCols(new String[]{"minute", "value"})
                .setOutputCol("features");

Dataset<Row> vectorData = assembler.transform(dataset);
```

I then fit this into a linear regression model:

```
LinearRegression lr = new LinearRegression();
LinearRegressionModel model = lr.fit(vectorData);
```

This is the part where I get stuck. How can I make predictions with this model? I want to find the value of `value` when `minute` is equal to a random minute, eg. 700.

How can I do that? How can I find a prediction/estimate of my Y value based on a random X value?

EDIT: Does the linear regression model differentiates between dependent and independent variable? How?

Comment: The Javadoc should clear this up for you: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/LinearRegressionModel.html. You can also export to PMML and visualize that.

Comment: I already did but the doc doesn't explain how to use the `predict()` function. It says it takes a `Vector` as a parameter. Why? Does that mean I need to convert a value to a vector and then pass it to this predict function? So if I have an Integer representing time, I need to convert it to a vector in order to make a prediction?

Comment: Yes - Vector how you encode your features in SparkML.

Comment: But if I already told my model that my features column consist of both the X and Y variables (minute and value), won't it ask me the same on the predict function, a vector with two dimensions? If that's the case then that doesn't work for me. Like I said, I want to predict the value of Y based on my X (minute).

Comment: There's a more fully featured example here: http://go.databricks.com/hubfs/notebooks/Pop._vs._Price_LR.html -- It appears that the last column is used as the target feature by default -- or the one called "label"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So thanks to the feedback of @RickMoritz and @JacekLaskowski I was able to figure out the solution:

LinearRegression does indeed have X and Y columns. The X column is the `features` column and the Y column is the `label` column.

So before fitting your dataset into a LinearRegression model, make sure to state your `label` and `features` columns. You can set your label column when you define your LinearRegression:

`LinearRegression lr = new LinearRegression().setLabelCol(Ycolumn_name);`

For the features column, ***make sure you convert your X column into vector type***, and then you can do the same:

`LinearRegression lr = new LinearRegression().setFeaturesCol(Xcolumn_name);`

Once you've done that you're all set. To get a prediction just convert your X value into a vector and put it on the `predict()` function of the LinearRegressionModel.

Answer (score 2):

I've only started with Spark MLlib and especially linear regression so I can only discuss technicalities (not why things work this way in machine learning).

> This is the part where I get stuck. How can I make predictions with this model?

Models are transformers (like `VectorAssembler`) that offers a very simple interface with [transform](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.Transformer@transform(dataset:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_]):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) operator.

> **transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame** Transforms the input dataset.

That's where you pass the dataset and get another dataset with `prediction` column back. That's by the way the general approach to train and make predictions.

The following will give you the predictions out of the features in the input dataset.

```
val dataset = ...
model.transform(dataset).select("prediction").show
```

---

I'd strongly recommend using Spark MLlib's ML Pipeline feature for the so-called **predictive analytics workflow** that makes the process of transforming a raw data to the format of an `Estimator` so much more pleasant. See [Machine Learning Library (MLlib) Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html) and especially [ML Pipelines](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html).

> **ML Pipelines** provide a uniform set of high-level APIs built on top of DataFrames that help users create and tune practical machine learning pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

here is the documentation about linear regression model

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

fit your XTrain,YTrain data to linear regresiion model. make sure that XTrain and Y train are dataframes.

use pandas to convert your data to dataframes.

now you can feed your test data to predict values

to get best estimator use grid search .
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html

Comment: On the tags it says I'm working with Apache Spark and Java. What you posted involves a totally different framework and programming language. It looks like it might work but it is not relevant to my question, unfortunately.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry. I overlooked it. I thought it was generic and posted scikit learn as it is widely used .

Comment: Yeah, no problem. I actually wanted to work with Python as it is easier to work with and has more support for ML than Java, but I was told to work with Java unfortunately.